# java template engine with good performance

Tags: template-engine

I am looking for a good template engine in terms of performance. I am dealing with a large amount of records (fetched from db, hence different object types), around 12 billion which needs to evaluated by this engine to genetate a string.

I have tested with Spring exp language, but seems slow as per our need. Simple string.format is quit faster( it is processing every record in 15 msec)

Ex: SomeEngine.evaluate(expression, parameterMap)

Is there any other option that I should look for. I dont think Velocity or Freemarker will be faster than this.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: what do you mean by "needs to be evaluated by this engine"? Can you provide some (pseudo-)code which should be performed by the template-engine?

Comment: @wero I have added little pseudo code